# Can I use javascript to retrieve the content header when setting the src on audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, mp3, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm using the HTML5 audio control to play an mp3 file that is streaming from the server:

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls" src="">
</audio>
```

And I am setting the `src` of that audio control dynamically, when a user clicks a button:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.src = "/api/audio/f56i4gi8lh";
    audio.load();
});
```

The audio is playing fine, but I also want to show the file name in a label when the audio starts streaming. The problem is that before I start streaming the audio from that url, I only know the file **id** and not the file name. That file **name** is contained in the header of the response (the response from `/api/audio/f56i4gi8lh`.

I can see the file name in the header using my F12 tools when I debug:

[image]

Is there a way to extract that filename from the header into a javascript variable using javascript or jQuery (while setting the `src` of the audio control)?

I would think it would be something along these lines:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.src = "/api/audio/f56i4gi8lh";
    audio.load(function(response) {
        var name = response.Header.filename;
    });
});
```

But I cannot find any documentation on anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but there's unfortunately nothing easy about it.

First off, your server configuration is going to have to properly support CORS for the domain on which your page is.

Next, you'll have to switch to using MediaSource Extensions so that you can request the media yourself with the Fetch API and intercept the response headers.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

As an alternative, you could look into using Web Workers to handle the fetching.  I haven't tried this myself so I don't have any specific advice, but it's my understanding you can do this and continue using the regular audio tag src like you are in your existing code.

Another (albeit less desirable) alternative is to make a separate HEAD request with the Fetch API.  This isn't great because this separate request may have a different response than your first request.  But, it is a possibility for you.